# Powershell - copy files recursively into a single folder that contains certain text

Tags: powershell

I have the following

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\sourcefolder -Recurse -File| Select-String "OBR\|101\|" -SimpleMatch  | Copy-Item -Destination \\destinationfolder
```

It copies all the files - however I want it to only copy files with the string `OBR|101|`

Any pointers? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: Please explain whether this string you're looking fo is part of the file name of part of the file's content. Also, why the last regex `OR` character (`|`) ?

Comment: Part of the file content. I have added SimpleMatch  to it's not treated as regex

Comment: For SimpleMatch (no regex used), you should not escape any characters. Just `Select-String "OBR|101|" -SimpleMatch`

Comment: Just hit me that's what it was - thank you